# What to call the duration from when billing start to the deadline

Tags: single-word-requests

If every month, I am allowed to pay my rent anytime between the 20th of that month and the 30th of that month, then what to call that 10 days period?

Comment: I can't imagine someone not taking your money earlier.

Comment: @John this is just an example, my mother tongue is not English. I am trying to translate some parts of my information system to English for foreign customers.

Comment: You can call it 'a window.' 'You must (do this etc) within this window each month.'

Comment: The straightforward '*10-day period*' works. What nuance would you like in the term you're asking for?

Comment: or a 'grace period' after which your payment in late.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term **payment window**.

Here is an example of its usage:

> The Commons Treasury Committee has accused the chancellor of delaying
>   introduction of the 30-day **payment window** for CGT on disposals of
>   residential property to help the government meet its fiscal rule
>   deadline in 2020/21.
>
> The new requirement for payment on account within 30 days of
>   completion of chargeable residential property disposals was originally
>   announced at Autumn Statement 2015 and intended to take effect in
>   April 2019. The Autumn Budget announced a deferral of the change by
>   one year, until April 2020.
>
> [www.taxjournal.com](https://www.taxjournal.com/articles/treasury-committee-rebukes-chancellor-over-cgt-payment-window-25012018)